# Object does not rotate around pivot point

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air, adobe

I have an object which looks like this:
[image]

When I try to rotate it using `[INSTANCENAME].rotation += 10;` 
it still rotates around the middle of the object. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done a little research, and apparently there is no direct way to change the pivot point programmatically, AFAIK. Rather odd, seeing as you can change it in the Flash Pro IDE. (For those reading, the pivot point is NOT the same as the registration point.)

[EDIT: Thinking more about it, I don't think the pivot point actually "exists", at least in the context of a programmable property. It only exists in the context of some tools in the Flash IDE.]

You will need to place your object ALONE inside another object, so that the desired pivot point of the inner object is over the center of the outer object. Then, rotate the outer object.

You can later control your object's "pivot point" by changing the position of the inner object.

Since the outer object's center moves depending on its size, and the position of the inner object determines the size of the outer object, you'd need to apply some math. The x position of the inner object would need to be equal to the distance from the desired pivot point on the inner object to the far right edge of that inner object. The same concept applies to the y position.

This can be accomplished both in the IDE directly, or through code, whichever you choose.

An example of code to change this dynamically. This function is inside the outer object. (You can get pivotX and pivotY off an event listener, if you want.) [Sorry, the code is untested.]

```
function newPivot(int pivotX, int pivotY):void
{
   inner.x = inner.width - pivotX;
   inner.y = inner.height - pivotY;
}
```

I hope that solves your problem!

Comment: Hmm. A pivot point of an object is a point within that object with (0,0) coordinates, and it's the same as registration point. When I apply rotation to an object, it rotates around (0,0) of itself. Has this been changed in Flash CS6? While yes, if you want an object to be rotated around another point, wrap it in the container sprite and adjust its x&y to match desired pivot point, then rotate not the object but its container.

Comment: No, the registration point is the point on the object that is considered (0,0). The pivot point is where rotations take place from. They CAN be the same (and sometimes are by default), but they aren't the same property. If you mess with the reg. point, you're going to throw all the internal coordinates off, and make positioning more difficult. If you simply change the pivot point (in the IDE or via the above method), you avoid that problem. It's been that way since I started in CS5.5, and probably longer based on documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way is to do like this.

1. Convert the image to a symbol(MovieClip). [you might have already done it].
2. Double Click on the MovieClip/Sprite to enter inside.
3. Move the Image so that the registration point align towards the pivot.

NB: Applicable only in case of FLASH IDE.

Comment: Can you elaborate on number three? And what does NB mean?

Comment: @user2789610 : Double click on the MovieClip to enter inside it. Now Move the Image (in your case the above image) so that the Handle is aligned to the center point (I'm not really sure if it shows you the center point). Check this one on getting the idea i mentioned [Editing registration point](http://www.kirupa.com/developer/mx/rpoint.htm)

& NB means : to draw attention to something of particular importance :)